# geting an objects array stored in an hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish I could get an array of objets stored in an hidden input.

Thanks

Here is the hidden input in the html page :

```html
<input type="hidden" name="idMusicians" value="[{&quot;id&quot;:7069,&quot;project_id&quot;:324,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Gator&quot;,&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Ali&quot;,&quot;instrument_id&quot;:28,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,&quot;,{&quot;id&quot;:7070,&quot;project_id&quot;:324,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Zhette&quot;,&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Annie&quot;,&quot;instrument_id&quot;:29,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,}]">
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
var musicians = $("#idMusicians").map(function(){
    var musician = this;
    return musician;        
}).get();
```

And this also without success :

```
var musicians = $("#idMusicians").data('value');
```

Comment: Your input is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value in your input if you give it an id and then use:

```
$("#idMusicians").val();
```

Once you have your value in a variable, you can parse it as JSON, which will then allow you to iterate over your array to access its objects. However, in order for `JSON.parse()` to work, the value in `value` needs to be valid JSON. At the moment, your value isn't valid JSON as it doesn't close your first object properly. If you fix this, you can then use `JSON.parse()` without getting errors.

See example below:

```js
const musicians = $("#idMusicians").val();
const res = JSON.parse(musicians);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="idMusicians" name="idMusicians" value="[{&quot;id&quot;:7069,&quot;project_id&quot;:324,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Gator&quot;,&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Ali&quot;,&quot;instrument_id&quot;:28,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:7070,&quot;project_id&quot;:324,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Zhette&quot;,&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Annie&quot;,&quot;instrument_id&quot;:29,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-08-02 15:48:07&quot;}]">
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is the id selector, but `idMusicians` is a name property. Try changing it to `id=idMusicians` or select by name attribute `$(input[name="idMusicians"])`

Comment: You're right, I did it. Nick Parsons gave me THE solution, thank's to him